# How to migrate customer skype to microsoft teams?

Tags: skype, office365, microsoft-teams, slack

I want to migrate customer skype accounts to teams. I want import contacts and messages. Google give answers for Skype for business but I dont find way to import messages. If it possible to copy data from skype to "for business" it would be nice.

When I export messages and contracts from web skype user account panel, I find that, this files are in CSV. I don't find option to import all to teams. So I thought about import CSV messages to Slack and then to Teams, but in microsoft tutorial I saw that private messages is not easy to import.

Maybe users can easy log in, because their Microsoft accounts domain will be add to Microsoft 365 and then all contracts and messages from customer skype will be added. Unfortunately I don't know that.

Comment: Have you asked your IT department for assistance?

Comment: I'm not a user. I work in IT department and want to copy messages of my users